# Phonegap do something in a 200 meter radius

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

Is there a way to determine if the phone is in a 200 radius of a fixed position?

for example, when the position is long 52.684694 lat 5.741550 i need to determine if i'm in a 200 meter range of the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`watchPosition` method in PhoneGap's geolocation library](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition) to add an event listener for significant location changes. You could then do some [fairly simple math](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript) in the callback to figure out distance. Don't forget to use `geolocation.clearWatch` to stop watching the current position when it's no longer needed — geolocation can drain a device's battery quickly.

Comment: Mhhh... allright! i'll take a look, but what kind of math do i need to apply? Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that both "`watchPosition` method in PhoneGap's geolocation library " and "fairly simple math" are links